# Saharian calima dust, apart of Fe2O3 does contain FeO?

Tags: geochemistry, geobiology

It is repeated often that Saharan calimas are fertilizing often Atlantic ocean. But I suppose that most of Saharan dust contains Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> and not FeO. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct. Typical sand is silica (white) with a little Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> (red) to give a "sand" color. FeO is black and over geological time in air, oxidizes further to Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub> with hydroxides and hydrates (black and dark brown) and eventually Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>.

Comment: Let me just add that "FeO" probably doesn't even exist in the top few tens of kms (or maybe even hundreds of kms) of the earth. It is common as a component in other minerals (such as fayalite olivine) but never on its own. Fe2O3 on the other hand, is a common mineral: hematite.